# having a check command as a complete model in Alloy

Tags: alloy

In the Alloy book (Software Abstractions) at page 132, it is said that the following command is a complete alloy model:

```
check {all p,q: univ -> univ, s: set S | (p.s).q = p.(s.q)}
```

I put this to alloy tool and execute, but the alloy complains about the **S**. Is this a mistake in the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like it.  If one replaces 'S' with 'univ', the expressions make sense and the Analyzer accepts the model.